# Is there any way to make tab shorter on a text box control?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The normal tab just indents the line a little to far in for what I am using it for. Is there any way to make the tab indents look smaller while still functioning as a normal tab?

Comment: Tab is a character.  How it gets rendered is up to the font, just like other characters.

Comment: so there is no way I can change it without changing the font?

Comment: You could capture the tab and replace it with multiple spaces.

Comment: Agreed with @SILENT. You can capture the key press event down, determine if it was a TAB, and then prevent the normal default, and return only 3 spaces, etc.

Comment: but then I wouldn't be able to differentiate between a tab 3 spaces and three actual spaces for when I try to save it

Comment: You could also substitute a different unicode whitespace character e.g. non breaking space.  You could convert back to internally tab as needed.